# How to dynamically import images in opengraph-image.tsx | Next.js 13 - App router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js13

Somehow it's throwing an error if you try to dynamically create URL and pass it to 'fetch', while passing it a static one would work perfectly fine.

Context: I have a list of players and on each page of the specific player I want to have opengraph image of that particular player. When I'm fetching my local image from public folder by using dynamic `id` segment path, I get an error that fetch failed; but if instead of '${id}' you put static id of any player, it will load it easily (for instance, by putting ../../../../public/assets/images/players/png/nameofaplayer.png the image of the "nameofaplayer" would load, but it's required to do for each player its own image). I wonder why is it has to do with dynamic URL?

```
// path - src/app/players/[id]/opengraph-image.tsx
import { ImageResponse } from 'next/server';

export const size = { width: 1200, height: 680 };
export const contentType = 'image/png';
export const runtime = 'edge';
export default async function og({ params }) {
  const {id} = params;
  const image = await fetch(new URL(`../../../../public/assets/images/players/png/${id}.png`, import.meta.url)).then(
    (res) => res.arrayBuffer()
  );
  const interBold = fetch(
    new URL('../../../../public/assets/fonts/Inter-Bold.ttf', import.meta.url)
  ).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())
  
  return new ImageResponse(
    <div
      style={{
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        fontSize: 52,
        fontWeight: 600,
        padding: '15px 20px',
        color: '#1e2124',
        margin: '0 auto',
      }}
    >
      {/* @ts-ignore */}
      <img src={image} width="425" height="430" alt={id} style={{ margin: '0 0 15px 0' }}/>
    </div>
  , {
    ...size,
    fonts: [
      {
        name: 'Inter',
        data: await interBold,
        style: 'normal',
        weight: 600,
      },
    ]
  }
  );
}
```

error: `Error [TypeError]: fetch failed`

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to use absolute path instead of relative and it did work:

```
const image = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/assets/images/players/png/${id}.png`).then(
  (res) => res.arrayBuffer()
);
```

You can put your `.env` variable of your site instead of hardcoded `localhost`'.